# Why does the dereference operator fail to return value pointed by a "pointer to an array" variable?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

Consider the program,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int a[][4] = {2,3,4,5,
                43,32,76,3
               };
  int *p;
  int (*q)[4];

  p = (int *)a;
  q = a;
  printf("%u\t%u", (unsigned int)p,(unsigned int)q);
  printf("\n%d\t%d",*(++p),*(++q));
  return 0;
}
```

In the above program, I have defined two pointers,

1) Integer pointer

2) Pointer to an Array

When compiled using the GCC compiler, I met with two doubts,

**Question 1:**

Why is that, the statement,

```
printf("\n%d\t%d",*(++p),*(++q));
```

returns an address when I try to dereference `(++q)`?

**Question 2:**

Is there any way I can use a "Pointer to an array" variable('q' - in this program) to access the consecutive element in a row?

Compiler: GCC; OS: Ubuntu

Comment: See [ask] and provide a [mcve]. `printf` does not return a pointer, resp. an address.

Comment: And **never ever** use a cast just to silence compiler warnings - unless you really understand and accept all implications oif the cast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `*(++q)` does not "return an address". It returns a result of type `int[4]`, which is an lvalue of *array* type. That lvalue refers to `a[1]` subarray of array `a`.

   This means that the title of your question is no accurate at all: the dereference operator in this case *does* return exactly what it is supposed to return. The pointer is declared as a pointer to an *array*, and the dereference operator evaluates to an lvalue of *array* type.

   However, immediately after that you use that array lvalue in a context where it *decays* to pointer type, just like any other array would (see [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying), [Why do arrays in C decay to pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291624/why-do-arrays-in-c-decay-to-pointers)). Passing an array as an argument to `printf` happens to be such a context. So, that original array lvalue decays to a pointer. That pointer value points to the beginning of `a[1]`, which is the same as `&a[1][0]`. That pointer value is passed to `printf` and you attempt to print it with `%d`.

   (Note that using `%d` in `printf` to print pointer values triggers undefined behavior.)
2. Well, you can access them in any way you wish

   ```
   q = a;
   q[1][1] = 42; // accesses `a[1][1]`
   ++q;
   (*q)[2] = 5; // accesses `a[1][2]`
   ```

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh: `printf("\n%d\t%d",*(++p),*(++q))` - the second variadic argument.

Comment: Right, I see now, thanks. Note-to-self: Pointer to array -> dereference -> pointer to first element of array (after decay).

Comment: Sir, if it is not too much to ask, can you please review the wordings of my answer here?

Answer (score 1):

This declaration

```
int (*q)[4];
```

declares a pointer to objects of type `int[4]`. To simplify the understanding you could introduce a typedef the following way

```
typedef int T[4];

T *q;
q = a;
```

So dereferencing the pointer you will get the pointed object of the type `T` that represents an array of type `int[4]`. As result using this object in the `printf` function

```
printf("\n%d\t%d",*(++p),*(++q));
                         ^^^^^
```

you will get the second "row" (due to incrementing the pointer `++q`) of the array `a` that is in turn a one-dimensional array of type `int[4]` that in turn is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

Thus the expression `*(++q)` has the type `int *` and points to the first element of the second "row" of the array `a`.

If you want to use this pointer to traverse the elements of the array `a` you can do it the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a[][4] = { { 2, 3, 4, 5 }, { 43, 32, 76, 3 } };

    int ( *q )[4] = a;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ); i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < sizeof( *q ) / sizeof( **q ); j++ )
        {
            printf( "%2d ", q[i][j] );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
 2  3  4  5 
43 32 76  3
```

That is `q[0]`  is the first "row" of the array `a`. You can write also just `*q`. `q[1]` is the second "row" of the array `a`. You may can write also like `*( q + 1 )`. To get access to the elements of each row you can apply the subscript operator like (the first row)

`q[0][i]` where `i` is some index value. Or you can write the same like `( *q )[i]`

and like (the second row) `q[1][i]` or `( *( q + 1 ) )[i]`

And the special expression like `**q` yields the first element of the first row of the array `a`.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** answer, dereferencing a pointer-to-an array produces an array, which, once passed as a function argument, decays to pointer to the first element of the array. So, the final *value* is of pointer type (the former and the later are of pointer to different type, but they are pointers, nonetheless).

---

That said, first of all

```
 printf("%u\t%u", (unsigned int)p,(unsigned int)q);
```

is implementation dependent behaviour as conversion of a pointer to an integer is implementation defined. If at all, you can cast the pointer to `uintptr_t` type and print using `PRIuPTR` format specifier to print the value.

Secondly, pointer arithmetic honors the data type. `q` is a pointer to an array of 4 `int`s. Once incremented, it points past the first array. But then, there's a mismatch in the supplied format specifier.

```
 printf("\n%d\t%d",*(++p),*(++q));
               ^^         ^^^^^^
```

To elaborate, `q` is of type pointer-to-array. Dereferencing that produces an array, now once the array is passed as an argument to a function, it decays to the pointer to the first element of the array. So, essentially, you're passing a pointer as the argument to `%d` format specifier, which is the mismatch, leading to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Finally, regarding the access to individual elements, you can either use

- `(*(q+m))[n]` --> First dereference `q` to obtain the array, then use indexing
- `q[m][n]` --> `q[m]` produces the array, then `n` is used as indexing to get individual element.