# Why this two sizeof gives different result?

Tags: c

I understand if you have an array, and you do sizeof, it gives you the number of bytes that block of memory occupies, but I have some confusion regarding the follow situation.

```
int mylen(const char *str) {
    return sizeof(str);
}

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "hello";

    printf("%d\n", sizeof(str)); // this gives 6
    printf("%d\n", mylen(str)); // this gives 8
}
```

I understand mylen is just returning the sizeof char pointer, therefore 8, but in that case, why the first one works? It this the subtle distinction between str and char *?

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question? `I understand if you have an array, and you do sizeof, it gives you the number of bytes that block of memory occupies` and `I understand mylen is just returning the sizeof char pointer, therefore 8`, which answers why the results are different.

Comment: `char str[]` is not a pointer? `const char*` is. There.

Comment: @DeiDei `str` in `char str[] = "hello";` is an array of 6 `char`.

Comment: Given `const char *str`, just what do you expect `sizeof(str)` to return?

Comment: `printf("%d\n", sizeof(str));` has undefined behavior. `sizeof` yields a `size_t`, not an `int`.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and response, second link in duplicate area answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same reason why in

```
char foo[6];
sizeof(foo);  // yields 6
```

and in

```
char *bar;
sizeof(bar);  // yields 8  (or in general: the size of a pointer on your system)
```

btw, since the result of the `sizeof`-operator is of type `size_t`, your `mylen()` should return `size_t` (defined in `<stddef.h>`) instead of `int`.

Also, if you want to `printf()` a `size_t` you'll have to use `"%zu"`, not `"%d"`.

For more detail you might want to read something on array-to-pointer decay: [Why do arrays in C decay to pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291624/why-do-arrays-in-c-decay-to-pointers)