# Are array names in function arguments treated differently than arrays declared locally (auto)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, parameter-passing, function-call

Please read the comments in the program below :

```
#include<stdio.h>
void test(char c[])
{
    c=c+2; //why does this work ?
    c--;
    printf("%c",*c);
}
int main()
{
    char ch[5]={'p','o','u','r'};
    //ch = ch+2;  //this is definitely not allowed on array names as they are not pointers
    test(ch);

    return 0;
}

OUTPUT
o
```

Comment: `c` is a pointer, `ch` is not.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but I recommend checking out: [Why do arrays in C decay to pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291624/why-do-arrays-in-c-decay-to-pointers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep in mind that the name of the array "decays" to a pointer to its first element. This means that `test(ch);` is equivalent to `test(&ch[0]);`.

Also, `void test(char c[])` is nothing but `void test(char* c)`, a pointer to a character. Pointers *can* be incremented or decremented which is why `c = c + 2` and `c--` compiles just fine.

Answer (score 0):

When an array is passed as function argument (among other cases), it decays to a pointer to the first element, and the function parameter which receives it is local to the function scope.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>   type *‘‘array of type’’* is converted to an expression with type *‘‘pointer to type’’* that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. [...]

So, in your case, inside `void test(char c[])` function call, `c` is just another pointer, which points to the first element of the array. Normal pointer arithmetic can be performed on that pointer.

In other words,

```
 void test(char c[]) { //....
```

is same as

```
 void test(char *c) { //....
```

So, you case is something similar to

```
int main(void)  //correcting the definition
{
    char ch[5]={'p','o','u','r'};
    //ch = ch+2;  //this is definitely not allowed on array names as they are not pointers

    char *c = &ch[0];   // this is what happens when you pass the array as function argument.
    c = c + 2;   // see, this is possible.

    test(ch);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array designators are immutable lvalues. That is you may not change an array designator such a way that ir would define another array.

Consider array designators as named memory extents.

As for your example then this function declaration

```
void test(char c[]);
```

is adjusted by the compiler the following way

```
void test(char *c);
```

that is a parameter having an array type is adjusted by the compiler to pointer. Thus for example these function declarations

```
void test(char c[100]);
void test(char c[10]);
void test(char c[1]);
void test(char c[]);
```

are equivalent and declare this one function

```
void test(char *c);
```

You nay include all these declarations in your program though they will be redundant.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(char c[100]);
void test(char c[10]);
void test(char c[1]);
void test(char c[]);
void test( char *c)
{
    c=c+2; 
    c--;
    printf("%c",*c);
}

int main( void )
{
    char ch[5]={'p','o','u','r'};
    test(ch);
}
```

To make it evident consider the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test( char c[] )
{
    printf( "sizeof( c ) = %zu\n", sizeof( c ) );
}

int main( void )
{
    char ch[5]={'p','o','u','r'};
    test( ch );
    printf( "sizeof( ch ) = %zu\n", sizeof( ch ) );
}
```

Its output is

```
sizeof( c ) = 8
sizeof( ch ) = 5
```

That is within the function `sizeof( c )` is equal to the size of a pointer (in used system it is equal to 8). While in main `sizeof( ch )` is the size of the array.

When you pass an array to such a function then the array designator is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. So these calls

```
test( ch );
test( &ch[0] );
```

are equivalent.

This means that within the function you deal with a pointer and you can change the value of the pointer using the pointer arithmetic.

Comment: The terminology in this answer is muddled. The C standard uses “designator” only for function designators and for the things that designate which parts of an aggregate to initialize (in `struct foo x = { .bar = 3 };`, `.bar` is a designator). Lvalues are said to designate objects, but lvalues may be computed, not immutable. E.g., if `x` is a pointer to an array, `*x` is an array (and `sizeof *x` would give the size of that array), but `*x` can take on different values at different times. And arrays do not need to be named; an array can be created via `malloc`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil English is not my native language so it is difficult to me to select a more appropriate word.

Answer (score -1):

In declarations of function parameters, an array declaration is automatically adjusted to be a pointer declaration, per C 2018 6.7.6.3 7:

> A declaration of a parameter as “array of *type*” shall be adjusted to “qualified pointer to *type*”,…

Thus `void test(char c[])` is effectively `void test(char *c)`.

In `main`, `ch` is an array, because it was declared with `char ch[5]…`, which is a normal declaration that is not adjusted. In `test`, `c` is a pointer.

When `main` calls `test` with `test(ch)`, the argument `ch` is an expression. In an expression, an array is automatically converted to a pointer in most cases because C 2018 6.3.2 3 says:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type “array of *type*” is converted to an expression with type “pointer to *type*” that points to the initial element of the array object…

Thus, when an array is passed to a function with a parameter declared as an array, the array is converted to a pointer and is passed for a parameter that was adjusted to be a pointer.

Note that only an outer array is adjusted. If the function parameter declaration is `int x[3][4]`, it is adjusted to be `int (*x)[4]`, a pointer to an array of 4 `int`. Only the array that is the parameter (the array of 3 arrays of 4 `int` above) is adjusted; other types within its composition are not adjusted.

### Aside

The C standard is not entirely clear about the effects of the adjustment. Using Apple LLVM 10.0.1 with clang-1001.0.46.4, the following program prints “Hello, world.”:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void foo(int a[printf("Hello, world.\n")]) {}

int main(void) { foo(0); }
```

This shows the array declaration was not completely adjusted to be a pointer declaration, as the expression specifying the array size was retained but would not be present in a pointer declaration.

Comment: If it's any help, GCC 9.1.0 also compiles the code and prints `Hello, World.` when run.  With minor massaging to test `a` before printing `a[0]`, it compiles under very stringent options, even with `-pedantic`.