# Why is <iterator>'s std::size not working with raw array parameters

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator, size, c++17

I usually work in an environment where the highest supported version of modern C++ is C++14. I was experimenting with `std::size` from `<iterator>` in c++17 and came across the following issue / problem / lack of understanding on my part.

In the following code snippet the use of of `size(a)` in `main` works correctly but the usage in `print` refuses to compile stating that `no matching function for call to 'size(int*&)'` exists.

I know there are other, better ways of doing this but I would like to know why it works in the one context and not the other.

For what its worth I used the following [online compiler](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php) and simply turned the `-std=c++17` flag on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

void print(int a[])
{
   for(int i = 0; i < size(a); i++)
        cout << a[i] << endl;
}

int main() 
{
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    cout << "Directly" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < size(a); i++)
        cout << a[i] << endl;

    cout << "Via function" << endl;
    print(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's because `a` in `print` is not an array, it's a pointer. There is no such thing in C++ (or C) as a *raw array parameter*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first invocation of `std::size` uses this function template signature (#3 in the overload set [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size)):

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t size(const T (&array)[N]) noexcept;
```

where the argument `array` has not decayed into a pointer. It's a raw array with the size encoded in its type. When you pass such an array to a function that accepts an `int[]` (or `int*`, that doesn't matter), the array decays into a pointer and the size is no longer part of the type. That's why `std::size(a)` can't compile. Concisely:

> Why is `<iterator>`'s `std::size` not working with raw array parameters?

It is, but you're trying to use it with a pointer, not an array parameter.

Comment: Also, `int[]` is actually a pointer to an array element, when it is a function parameter.

Comment: So this is one of those cases where are arrays are basically like pointers except when they aren't?

Comment: @DuncanACoulter Exactly. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291624/why-do-arrays-in-c-decay-to-pointers) for example.

Comment: @DuncanACoulter I find it best to first memorise that a function parameter may not be an array (reference to an array I possible though). Then that array parameters can be declared, but that declaration is adjusted to be a pointer and not an array at all.

Comment: @eerorika  I should have suspected it was a pointer-decay thing. As soon as this answer came in I realized what was going on.