# Array as a parameter without a length

Tags: c

I have a couple of questions about this code (I don't know what it does, it's from an exam).
What does it mean when the array is passed like this: `nums[]`? And what does `nums + 1` mean? If `nums` is an array, what does it mean to add 1 to it?

```
int f(int nums[], int n){
  if(n > 1) {
    if(nums[0] < nums[1]) {
      return 1 + f(nums + 1, n - 1);
    }
    else {
      return f(nums + 1, n - 1);
    }
  }
  else return 0; 
}
```

Comment: While there's nothing wrong with asking questions, if you're puzzled by this there's a strong chance you need a better [C reference book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to work from.

Comment: In C this is a function of how [arrays decay into pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291624/why-do-arrays-in-c-decay-to-pointers), so `int nums[]` is actually `int* nums` in effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C arrays cannot be passed by value to a function.

If you write something like

```
int a[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
// ....
int result = f(a, 4);
//             ^ The array "decays" to a pointer
```

What the function receives as parameters (passed by value) are a *pointer* to the first element of the array `a` and the size of the array (hopefully the correct one).

In the declaration of such a function, some use (and recommend) the notation showed in the question as a "documentation" of the fact that we want to pass an array, but it *may* be misleading, if the coder forgets that said parameter is *just* a pointer.

Given the use (purely accademic, it makes no sense to implement that algorithm as a recursive function), I'd find more descriptive the `*`:

```
int f(const int *nums, size_t n) {
  //  ^^^^^     ^  
}
```

> And what does `nums + 1` mean?

The result of `num + 1` is a *pointer* which points to the element immediately *after* the one pointed by `num`.

The recursive calls just traverse the array, one element at the time (note that the "size" is decreased accordingly), counting the times that two subsequent element are in increasing order. Would you be able to rewrite that function, without the recursive calls, using a loop?

Answer (score 1):

`int nums[]` is an array of `int`s. The `[]` denote that it's an array. The `int` denotes that the array contains `int`s.

`num + 1` points to the second position in the array, so the call basically calls the same function but passing the whole array minus the first element.

Comment: Quibble: `n+1` doesn't "access the second position in the array". I think you mean `nums + 1`, and that doesn't access, either, it just increments the pointer by one "slot". Actual access would be `nums[1]` or `*(nums + 1)`, and even then only if read or written to indirectly.

Comment: @tadman you're right! I messed up writing it. I meant that on the call inside the function, the pointer to the second element in the array is passed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe looking at the function from the side of the function prototype you will see more sense of this:

```
       int f(int[], int n);
```

Here `f()` is declared to return an `int` and use two arguments: the first is an address of an array of `int`, the second *is* an `int`.

Since inside `f()` you may want to know how many `int`'s are in the vector, it is common to the second argument to be number of elements in the array. Just as an example. Any similarity with the pair

```
        int argc, char** argv
```

is because it is the same thing: the system builds a list of the arguments passed on the command line and constructs the `argv` array. And passes `argc` as the number of arguments in the array.

C does pointer arithmetic, in a sense that if `x` points to an `int` `(x+1)` points to the `x` plus the `sizeof()` an `int`. This is fantastic in order to abstract things like memory, registers and hardware.

In this way, when you call `f()` again passing 1 + the original argument you are just calling `f()` and passing the array beginning at the next position.

Back to your example, consider `f()` just

```
int f(int nums[], int n)
{
    printf("First int is %d\n", nums[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

where `f()` just writes down the first int of the block, and the code

```
int f(int[], int n);

int main(int arg, char** argv)
{
    const int one[4] = { 1,2,3,4 };
    const int other[2] = { 3,4 };
    f(one, 4);
    f(other, 2);
    f(other + 1, 3'000);
    return 0;
};
```

it shows

```
First int is 1
First int is 3
First int is 4
```

And you see that in the 3rd call `f()` gets the array other starting at `4`, the second element.

Comment: What is `3'000` supposed to mean?

Comment: You can use single quotes to separate digits in C, like the underline in java. It makes no difference except making it easier to read, like 1'000'000 for a million. Sure, can make it harder to read also, as in        ` rows = 1'0'0'0'0'0'0;`
As far as the compiler is concerned means nothing

Comment: This new surprising syntax is not part of the C Standard up to and including the upcoming C2x version. It was introduced in C++ only, despite its inconsistency with existing lexical parsers and preprocessors. Using underscores for this as in java and javascript would have been less problematic: `3_000` a valid C preprocessing token, but `3'000` is not. The question is tagged `[c]`, so this syntax is inappropriate here.

Comment: This compiles ok on Microsoft and Intel compilers for years. I was not aware that gcc or CLang would create problems on this. Thanks for pointing it. I read now in the docs that CLang and gcc that it should compile adding some configuration but I had no time to test it. In C++ it goes well, as expected.